# New clients cannot connect to Django site when site are being used by other clients

Tags: django, apache, deployment, static-files

We have a Django based web application that is being deployed with Apache and mod_wsgi. The users logs in and can start some CPU-bound processes that can take up to 1-2 minutes.

Our problem is, when these CPU-bound processes are being run, the new clients cannot even load the site. Even if they can load it and enter their credentials and press log in button, the site is not opening before the ongoing processes are completed.
DEBUG option is False in deployment environment. We are not using `django.contrib.staticfiles` `serve()` function to serve our static files.

How can I find the reason behind this delay?

I suspect that this happens because static content are not being served with a different server? How can I make sure that this is the problem?

If that is the problem, can serving the static files with a different virtual host solve the issue?

Due to company policy, I cannot share the code directly here. However please let me know if there is any other information I need to elaborate.

Thanks for your time and attention in advance.

Comment: How are these CPU-bound processes being run? Can you give examples with sensitive info removed? All your threads/workers might be busy, increasing their number may help

Comment: Is there a way to make site accessible even if all Apache threads/workers are busy? Or can we say that it is simply happening because all the resources (threads/workers) are being used?